# Play Anorm table column alias cannot be found

Tags: mysql, scala, jdbc, playframework, anorm

I have a problem with aliasing in Play Anorm using MySQL JDBC.. The error is

`[RuntimeException: qty not found, available columns : ri_id, ri_id, detailri.po_id, po_id, detailri.product_id, product_id, product.description, description, detailri.received_qty, received_qty, qty, qty]`

I had run other query using aliasing, luckily I don't have any problem however for this query it shows error..

Query:

```
"""select CAST(ri_id as CHAR(10)) as ri_id, detailri.po_id, detailri.product_id, description, detailri.qty as received_qty, CAST(detailpo.qty as CHAR(10)) as qty from detailri, product, detailpo where ri_id = {idRI} and detailri.po_id = detailpo.po_id and detailri.product_id = product.id and detailpo.product_id = product.id group by detailri.ri_id, detailri.po_id, detailri.product_id"""
```

Parser:

```
val PIdetailParser: RowParser[PIdetail]={
    get[String] ("ri_id") ~
    get[String] ("po_id") ~
    get[String] ("product_id") ~
    get[String] ("description") ~
    get[Int] ("received_qty") ~
    get[String] ("qty ") map({
        case ri_id~po_id~product_id~description~received_qty~qty => PIdetail(ri_id,po_id,product_id,description,received_qty,qty)
    })
}
```

So, I already added `useOldAliasMetadataBehavior=true` to my JDBC (application.conf), but stil no luck.. Really need your help here..

Comment: You have an unnecessary space in your `get[String] ("qty ")`. Replace it with `get[String] ("qty")` and I hope it should work fine

Comment: Yup, you are right bro... thanks for your help..
My silly mistake.. @,@